# echo before deleting file through batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running something like

```
for %j in (c:\user\data) do if not %j == Important del %i
```

so that all files get deleted except this one Important however, before I run this I wanted to make sure that script will only delete which I meant to hence, I wanted to see the files being affected before I run so I tried using echo as

```
for %i in ("c:\user\data") do echo %i
```

but this does not seem working, I am expecting to see all the files in this directory so that I would be sure about the files being affected but I do not see anything, no error or anything. It just looks CMD opens and closes very fast. Can someone please help me..

Comment: Re "this does not seem working" (sic): (1) what should happen? (2) what did happen? Those are two of the three things that *every* problem report should have (the third being the smallest piece of code exhibiting the problem).

Comment: @paxdiablo, I wanted to see the list of the files being affected by this script but when I run this, noting happens. I do not see any error or anything. for example, I have 10 files in this folder including the one, I do not want to delete, I was expecting to see the list of the all the 10 files.

Comment: you want to process a list of files, so actually giving it a chance to get files should help. Try `for %i in ("c:\user\data\*") do echo %i`

Comment: @Stephan, tried this one but again nothing happens, I did see the cmd flicking, that's it. I also added the pause at the end but no luck..

Comment: wait - how do you start that line? The syntax is meant to be executed directly at a command prompt.

Comment: @Stephan, I am running this through batch file, not directly at the command prompt..

Comment: then use `%%i` instead of `%i`. Described in `for /?`.

Comment: @Stephan, thanks for the suggestion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to refer to the contents of the directory in your condition, rather than merely the directory itself. From command line:

```
for %i in (c:\user\data\*) do echo %i
```

And if you're doing it inside a batch file, then you need to add double percent signs for your loop variable:

```
for %%i in (c:\user\data\*) do echo %%i
```

More info on syntax [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Comment: Thanks, so that mean my other syntax is also wrong and should be prefixed by %% instead of single %?

Comment: @Viki2016, open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?` and read the help. It clearly states the doubling of the percent symbols.

Comment: If you're running from the command line, single % is fine, but within batch files, it must be double %.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your script to work like this:

```
cd "C:/user/data"

for /r %%i in (*) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems working but I only see the files not the Sub folders, any suggestions?

Comment: @Viki2016: try `echo %%~fi` - described in `for /?`