# Delete all folders except one

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, rmdir

I want to delete all files and folders in my `C:\temp` except one specific folder (`C:\temp\123`) which contains a lot of files and subfolders.

I tried with `pushd "c:\temp\123" && rd /s /q "c:\temp"` but it deletes all subfolders and files in `c:\temp\123`.

Can any one please help on the above?

Comment: Use google to [find examples](https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow%20batch%20file%20delete%20everything%20except) in a couple of seconds, here's one: [Windows batch script to delete everything in a folder except one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3009151)

Comment: Do you really work with **MS-DOS**, the OS from the 1980s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it the following way:

```
pushd "C:\Temp" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="123" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd
```

This is very similar to this approach: [Batch command to delete everything (sub folders and files) from a folder except one file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163035).