# Remove everything in the path except some files in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal, windows-7-x64, delete-file

When it comes to Windows command prompt, I always get confused about path, which seems so easy to grasp in Linux Terminal counterparts.

What I wanna do is, I want to delete everything(both files and folders in one command) in the path (for eg. `pub\static` directory path) except a file called `.htaccess` relative from my root directory(`C:\wwwroot\Magento2`), which is open in Windows command prompt.

How can I do this, I tried the below `for` loop, but it deletes `.htaccess` instead. Also how to avoid `for` loop altogether but get the job done as I described (relative from root directory) ?

```
for %i in (C:\wwwroot\Magento2\pub\static\*) do if not %i == .htaccess del %i
```

So I googled a bit and tried below one, but it doesn't do anything:

```
FOR /D %p IN ("C:\wwwroot\Magento2\pub\static\*.*") DO ( IF NOT %p == .htaccess ( IF EXIST %~sp\NUL ( RMDIR "%p" /S /Q ) ELSE ( DEL /F "%p" ) ) )
```

Comment: This is much, much easier in PowerShell.

Comment: Also: What should happen if a subdirectory contains _only_ the file `.htaccess`? Should we remove the subdirectory or not?

Comment: Only the .htaccess directly inside `static` folder should remain, the rest of the content inside `static` folder should be gone for good.

Comment: I tried some command syntaxex but I cannot create a for loop with nested if else that could span multiple lines and that could run in command prompt without batch file.

Comment: Don't use a batch file. Use PowerShell.

Comment: I cannot install Powershell, as my sysadmin won't allow in office system. There must be some other way.

Comment: PowerShell is built into the OS on Windows Server 2008 R2 and newer and Windows 7 and later. There is no install needed.

Comment: Ok then can you give me Powershell counterpart command for this ?

Comment: I created an answer that has an example of how to do this easily in PowerShell.

Comment: Ok just one thing, can I set default directory to open Powershell in ?

Comment: That is a separate question. Start by reading the PowerShell documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch command to delete everything (sub folders and files) from a folder except one file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159922/batch-command-to-delete-everything-sub-folders-and-files-from-a-folder-except)

Comment: I don't want a long list of commands like in that question, I just want one liner just like it is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Single PowerShell command:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Magento2\pub\static -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -ne ".htaccess" } | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Comment: Well it gives this error `An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:1 char:4
+   | <<<<  Where-Object { $_.Name -ne ".htaccess" } | Remove-Item -Recurse
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement`

Comment: Even if I don't have administrator access then also I can open and run commands in Powershell ?

Comment: You don't have to be administrator. Also, the above two lines are a single command. The newline is for readability. I moved the pipe character to the correct place.